# Plotear (o graficar) un lm

Tags: r

Calcule un modelo de regresión polynomial en base a unos datos que obtuve a campo, mi problema es graficarlos mostrando los puntos.
Les dejo el script y una muestra de datos, además de una gráfica de un modelo no lineal para que quede de muestra de lo que busco.

```
IAFT1 <- lm(IAF ~ Dia + I(Dia^2)-1, data = dataT1IAF)
summary(IAFT1)
```

Data:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/1budbw9awzjfc7t/Dudas.xlsx?dl=0

Y este gráfico (si bien no es el mismo modelo) es un ejemplo de lo que busco.
[image: Ejemplo de lo que busco]

Comment: Hola Germán, te respondí más abajo, creo que con ese código sale el gráfico que estás buscando. Lo hice con ggplot, en mi opinión más fácil para estas lides que los plots base de R, pero debería ser posible. Si lo que estás buscando no es plotear la serie de datos original y la curva sino los valores predichos por favor aclaralo, eso se hace de otra manera. Por último una aclaración: tu modelo no es un GLM, es un LM, donde la variable dependiente es continua. Te sugiero corregirlo en la pregunta.

Comment: Hola, es justo lo que buscaba, muchas gracias. Ya realice la modificación que recomendaste. Te molesto con una pregunta más ¿Cómo puedo cambiar la etiqueta con el nombre de los ejes?

Comment: Actualicé la respuesta con y agregué la función `labs()` con las anotaciones y señalé una opción para desactivar la banda de ic. Si esta es la respuesta que estabas buscando podés aceptarla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No sé si esto es exactamente lo que estás buscando, pero el gráfico resultante está hecho con los datos que cargaste y la especificación del modelo lineal.

## Librerías

```
library(tidyverse)  #Para la estructura de datos tribble y el gráfico
```

## Capturo los datos:

```
tribble(
~Trat,  ~Bloque,    ~Dia,   ~IAF,
"T1",      "A",      1,   0,
"T1",      "B",      1,   0,
"T1",      "C",      1,   0,
"T1",      "A",      44,  0.88,
"T1",      "B",      44,  0.75,
"T1",      "C",      44,  0.80,
"T1",      "A",      53,  2.16,
"T1",      "B",      53,  1.63,
"T1",      "C",      53,  1.63,
"T1",      "A",      67,  1.81,
"T1",      "B",      67,  1.90,
"T1",      "C",      67,  1.68,
"T1",      "A",      82,  2.10,
"T1",      "B",      82,  1.29,
"T1",      "C",      82,  1.16,
"T1",      "A",      97,  2.01,
"T1",      "B",      97,  1.46,
"T1",      "C",      97,  1.16) -> dataT1IAF
```

## Ajusto el modelo

En sentido estricto no es necesario, ggplot lo hará de nuevo.

```
IAFT1 <- lm(IAF ~ Dia + I(Dia^2)-1, data = dataT1IAF)
```

## Genero el gráfico con ggplot:

Voy a usar dos elementos geométricos de esta librería: `geom_point()` para los puntos *x y* y `geom_smooth()` para graficar la curva de ajuste del modelo. Por defecto grafica tb la banda del intervalo de confianza. A `geom_smooth()` hay que especificarle la fórmula del modelo en su idioma (i.e. usando los nombres de variable que toma ggplot y que especificamos con argumento `aes()`) y el tipo de modelo que estamos ajustando (lm, glm, loess, etc.).

```
dataT1IAF %>%                                #Datos
  ggplot(aes(x=Dia, y=IAF)) +                #Mapeo los ejes x y y, en adelante así los llamaré.
    geom_point() +                           #Genero los puntos, uno para cada par de x y y
geom_smooth(formula = y ~ x + I(x^2)-1,      #Espefico el modelo: uso las variables internas de ggplot. 
            method = "lm",                   #Por defecto ajusta un loess, aclaro que quiero un lineal.
            se=TRUE) +                       #Graficar el intervalo de confianza. FALSE sólo la curva de ajuste. 
  labs(title="Crecimiento en MS de T1",      #Etiqueta de título: string encomillado. 
       x="Tiempo (dds)",  
       y="KgMS/ha", 
       caption="Elaboración propia con datos de \nla n antecedida por una barra invertida\n marca un corte de línea.") + 
  theme_minimal()                            #Un tema simple para los gráficos.
```

[image: Puntos y curva de ajuste con ggplot2]